# Add a new column with sequence number depending on groupby of other column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column in panda dataframe where a sequence number will be filled out by each group.

In below, you can see the sample new column.

Here, when TYPID is zero it has 5 entry and when this is belong to same SID,SEMID,TYP,TYPID group then the NEW column is filled up with a sequence number (1, 2, 3, 4 - which has to maintain TID sequence)

| ind | SID | SEMID | TID | TYP | TYPID | NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 451 | A | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 450 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 452 | A | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 455 | P | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 456 | D | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 457 | D | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 5 | 458 | R | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 5 | 459 | A | 0 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 | 5 | 460 | A | 0 | 1 |

How can I achieve this in python?
I am totally  new to Python. It would be helpful if any expert help on this.

Thank you in advance.